# VLOOKUP Error - EXCEL

Tags: excel

I am trying to use VLOOKUP for the following:
Column A has all my data ids ( numbers) and Column B has a subset of my data ids in coulmn A

I need to get a list of all the ids which do not exist in Column B.

My VLOOKUP function looks like this:

```
= VLOOKUP(A1,B:B,2,FALSE)
```

I keep getting #N/A and #REF errors. I am not sure why.

Can some one please tell me what I am doing wrong. I am going on and on trying everything and nothing seems to be working.

Is my formula incorrect?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're returning the 2nd column when your array is only 1 column. The 2 needs to be a 1.

```
=VLOOKUP(A2, B:B, 1, FALSE)
```

Comment: I added the code sample, if that doesn't work, can you share your data to see what you are comparing? It's possible you're not matching the same data types.

Comment: You'll get #n/a if the number in a1 isn't in column b, otherwise you should get the value in a1. You could do something like this if you don't want the error message:
    =IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,B:B,1,FALSE)),A1,"in list")

Comment: yes that worked. Some of the rows seemed to have some error. I clicked and it seemed to work. Thank you guys( Duniyadnd and eggplant_parm) for all the help.